# Title bar is showing on "Desktop" in Cinnamon

Tags: titlebar, show-desktop

In my Ubuntu 14.04 with Cinnamon desktop, the title bar is showing in the desktop. I have to tried Google for solutions but to no avail.
[image: Desktop screenshot]